# Does kafka hdfs sink connector support topic level key and value converter?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In hdfs sink connector, I need to configure key and value converter at topic level i.e. different topic using different converter . Is it possible  ?

Answer (score 1):

Converters are properties that can be overridden at the Connector level. This means that a Connector instance can override the values that are globally set for converters within the Connect worker's configuration.

Therefore, although a per-topic override is not possible, grouping the topics that use the same converter types, each in a single connector instance, could achieve something close to what you describe in a more practical way.

Comment: Yes this is what I did finally to achieve the goal

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create different worker config files for the topics you'd like to use different key/value converters.

For example, if you'd like to parse a topic with Avro key then use

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

while for another (say in JSON format without schemas) you can use

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Then, you can run these worker config files in [distributed mode](https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.0/connect/userguide.html#distributed-worker-configuration).

Comment: I am already running in distributed mode , and our workers are topic agnostic. Tying worker to a topic would be difficult to manage from deployment and maintenance perspective on a large cluster

Comment: @LijuJohn Yes this is correct but I am afraid that there is no other workaround for your requirement since you need topic-specific configuration.